# Microphone sound level control on mac using java

Tags: java, macos

I want to control the Microphone sound level on OSX using java.I used  below source code but don't support on Mac OS. Is there any way control the Microphone sound volume level on OSX using java?

```
public static void setDeviceSensitivity(final int sensitivity) {
    final Port lineIn;
    //  Mixer.Info[] mixerInfoPool=AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();

    final Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(null);
    try {
        if (mixer.isLineSupported(Port.Info.LINE_IN)) {
            lineIn = (Port) mixer.getLine(Port.Info.LINE_IN);
            lineIn.open();
        } else if (mixer.isLineSupported(Port.Info.MICROPHONE)) {
            lineIn = (Port) mixer.getLine(Port.Info.MICROPHONE);
            lineIn.open();
        } else if (mixer.isLineSupported(Port.Info.HEADPHONE)) {
            lineIn = (Port) mixer.getLine(Port.Info.HEADPHONE);
            lineIn.open();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Unable to get Input Port");
            return;
        }
        lineIn.getControls();

        if (lineIn.isControlSupported(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN)) {
            System.out.println("kewl");
        }

        final CompoundControl cc = (CompoundControl) lineIn.getControls()[0];
        final Control[] controls = cc.getMemberControls();
        for (final Control c : controls) {
            if (c instanceof FloatControl) {
                System.out.println("BEFORE LINE_IN VOL = "
                        + ((FloatControl) c).getValue());
                ((FloatControl) c).setValue((float) sensitivity / 100);
                System.out.println("AFTER LINE_IN VOL = "
                        + ((FloatControl) c).getValue());
            }
        }
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the microphone:

```
    Mixer.Info microphone = null;
    for (Mixer.Info info : AudioSystem.getMixerInfo()) {
        System.out.println(info);
        if (info.getName().equals("Port Built-in Microphone")) {
            System.out.println("found " + info);
            microphone = info;
        }            
    }

    final Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(microphone);
```

Comment: What is this? An error mesage? Plese [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30073121/edit) your question if you have additional code.

Comment: I have used your code,but there is an error. 
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.media.sound.PortMixer$FloatCtrl cannot be cast to javax.sound.sampled.CompoundControl

Comment: Why do you do this: `final CompoundControl cc = (CompoundControl) lineIn.getControls()[0];`?